# How can I prevent double hrules with longtable?

Tags: longtable, booktabs

A project I'm working on involves a glossary that is generated via some macros, and uses `longtable` to be typeset. Now, each section of the glossary is separated from each other with a `\midrule` from the `booktabs` package. Now, this works well enough, and looks good, but there is one problem: when a glossary section ends at the same time as a page, there ends up being a double rule, a `\midrule` followed by a `\bottomrule`. Obviously, this doesn't look too good. Here's the code I'm working with at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,hyperref,multirow,booktabs,fullpage}

\newcommand{\GlossarySection}[2]{%
\multirow{1}{*}{\LARGE\bfseries #1} & foo  & n & lorem ipsum dolor sit &
\multirow{1}{*}{\LARGE\bfseries #2} & foo  & n & consectetur adipiscing elit \\*
& bar  & v & Maecenas sed purus       & & bar  & v & at ipsum placerat luctus \\*
& baz  & p & Nullam luctus id tellus  & & baz  & p & Ut ac ultricies neque \\*
& qux  & v & Aenean consequat commodo & & qux  & v & in sodales metus ultrices \\*
& buux & n & Phasellus tincidunt      & & quux & n & vitae pulvinar nisi mollis \\
\midrule}

\begin{document}\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{c>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}lc>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\caption{My Glossary}\label{tab:gloss} \\

\toprule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{8}{l}{%
\emph{\small\tablename\ \thetable{}: \nameref{tab:gloss}
--- continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
\endhead

\bottomrule \multicolumn{8}{r}{\emph{\small Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\GlossarySection{A}{B}
\GlossarySection{C}{D}
\GlossarySection{E}{F}
\GlossarySection{G}{H}
\GlossarySection{I}{J}
\GlossarySection{L}{M}
\GlossarySection{N}{O}
\GlossarySection{P}{Q}
\GlossarySection{R}{S}
\GlossarySection{T}{U}
\GlossarySection{V}{W}
\GlossarySection{Y}{Z}

\end{longtable}\end{center}\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the double rule looks less than ideal. Now an obvious solution would be just to leave out the `\midrule` at page breaks. There are a number of problems with this: One, the code for my project generates each sections using macros (in a similar manner to the contrived example I've included here). Secondly, and perhaps more importantly, *where* the pagebreaks occur is not always going to be predictable and might change when my content is edited. What would be ideal is somehow to only conditionally insert the `\midrule` if it isn't adjacent to the footer.

Comment: Off-topic: A `longtable` enviroment is centered horizontally by default. No need to encase it in a `center` environment.

Comment: not only is longtable centred by default it is always full width so `center` has no effect other than add extra vertical space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for example can you comment both commands `\bottomrule` in the head definitions.

And as @Mico mentioned in his comment:

> A `longtable` environment is centered horizontally by default -- no need
>   to encase it in a `center` environment.

See the following MWE (changed code marked with `<================`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,multirow,booktabs,fullpage,hyperref}

\newcommand{\GlossarySection}[2]{%
\multirow{1}{*}{\LARGE\bfseries #1} & foo  & n & lorem ipsum dolor sit &
\multirow{1}{*}{\LARGE\bfseries #2} & foo  & n & consectetur adipiscing elit \\*
& bar  & v & Maecenas sed purus       & & bar  & v & at ipsum placerat luctus \\*
& baz  & p & Nullam luctus id tellus  & & baz  & p & Ut ac ultricies neque \\*
& qux  & v & Aenean consequat commodo & & qux  & v & in sodales metus ultrices \\*
& buux & n & Phasellus tincidunt      & & quux & n & vitae pulvinar nisi mollis \\
\midrule%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{c>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}lc>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\caption{My Glossary}\label{tab:gloss} \\

\toprule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{8}{l}{%
\emph{\small\tablename\ \thetable{}: \nameref{tab:gloss}
--- continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
\endhead

%\bottomrule % <========================================================
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\emph{\small Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

%\bottomrule % <========================================================
\endlastfoot

\GlossarySection{A}{B}
\GlossarySection{C}{D}
\GlossarySection{E}{F}
\GlossarySection{G}{H}
\GlossarySection{I}{J}
\GlossarySection{L}{M}
\GlossarySection{N}{O}
\GlossarySection{P}{Q}
\GlossarySection{R}{S}
\GlossarySection{T}{U}
\GlossarySection{V}{W}
\GlossarySection{Y}{Z}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

**Update:**

One version with color instead `\midrule`.  With the command `\rowcolor{gray!30!white}` you get the next line in the table with a light gray background (see documentation of package `xcolor` with `texdoc xcolor`).  See that I loaded package `xcolor` with option `table`.

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,array,multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % <==========================================
\usepackage{hyperref} % <===============================================

\newcommand{\GlossarySection}[2]{%
\multirow{1}{*}{\LARGE\bfseries #1} & foo  & n & lorem ipsum dolor sit &
\multirow{1}{*}{\LARGE\bfseries #2} & foo  & n & consectetur adipiscing elit \\*
& bar  & v & Maecenas sed purus       & & bar  & v & at ipsum placerat luctus \\*
& baz  & p & Nullam luctus id tellus  & & baz  & p & Ut ac ultricies neque \\*
& qux  & v & Aenean consequat commodo & & qux  & v & in sodales metus ultrices \\*
\rowcolor{gray!30!white} % <============================================
& buux & n & Phasellus tincidunt      & & quux & n & vitae pulvinar nisi mollis \\
%\midrule% <============================================================
}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}lc>{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}c<{.}l}
\caption{My Glossary}\label{tab:gloss} \\

\toprule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{8}{l}{%
\emph{\small\tablename\ \thetable{}: \nameref{tab:gloss}
--- continued from previous page}} \\
\toprule
\endhead

\bottomrule % <========================================================
\multicolumn{8}{r}{\emph{\small Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot

\bottomrule % <========================================================
\endlastfoot

\GlossarySection{A}{B}
\GlossarySection{C}{D}
\GlossarySection{E}{F}
\GlossarySection{G}{H}
\GlossarySection{I}{J}
\GlossarySection{L}{M}
\GlossarySection{N}{O}
\GlossarySection{P}{Q}
\GlossarySection{R}{S}
\GlossarySection{T}{U}
\GlossarySection{V}{W}
\GlossarySection{Y}{Z}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

gives you as result (with colored last line and `\bottomrule` at the end of each page):

[image]

Comment: Right, but the problem here is that the the bottom always ends up being a ``\midrule`` instead of a ``\bottomrule``, and looks unbalanced.