# longtable: avoiding the combined midrule and foot rule at page bottom

Tags: longtable, tabu

Good day everyone!

I'm looking for suggestions on a longtable. When the table spans pages, there are occurrences where a midrule is subsequently followed by a foot rule. The definition appears:

```
begin{longtable}{@{}p{.33/columnwidth}p{.67/columnwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Topic & Subtopic \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
topic1 & subtopic1.1 \\
       & subtopic1.2 \\
       & subtopic1.3 \\* \midrule
topic2 & subtopic2.1 \\
       & subtopic2.2 \\
       & subtopic2.3 \\* \midrule
...
\end{longtable}
```

Before pagebreaks there is a change that \midrule is immediately followed by \bottomrule, and one see two lines appear at the bottom of the page.

Any suggestions on how to address this? Is there a way to "merge" rules? Or avoid it somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: before continuing to use tabu read the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu.

Comment: Appreciate the link.

Comment: Updated the example to longtable. I am confirming the behavior: a midrule followed immediately by a bottomrule.

Comment: The following might be related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331488/134144

Comment: I agree that it is related. The answer seems to be "don't".

Comment: The example is not complete and so can not be used to test the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package. And there are no double rules at page breaks with `longtblr` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=5cm,width=7cm,height=4.1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Title}
]{colspec={@{}X[l]X[l,2]@{}},rowhead=1}
\toprule[red5]
Topic  & Subtopic \\
\midrule[purple5]
topic1 & subtopic1.1 \\
       & subtopic1.2 \\
       & subtopic1.3 \\
\midrule[teal5]
topic2 & subtopic2.1 \\
       & subtopic2.2 \\
       & subtopic2.3 \\
\midrule[teal5]
topic3 & subtopic3.1 \\
       & subtopic3.2 \\
       & subtopic3.3 \\
\midrule[teal5]
topic4 & subtopic4.1 \\
       & subtopic4.2 \\
       & subtopic4.3 \\
\midrule[teal5]
topic5 & subtopic5.1 \\
       & subtopic5.2 \\
       & subtopic5.3 \\
\bottomrule[azure5]
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]